# Drupal autocreate custom content type on registration

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, content-type

I have created a new content type for storing additional user data (outside of the standard profile) page. This content type is only viewable by the user and the admin.

What I would like is that when a user registers this custom content type is automatically created for them so they can then populate it. How can this be achieved?

Comment: You say you want to "autocreate a custom content type", but I think you mean "autocreate a node of my custom content type", is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module - module allows site administrators to define conditionally executed actions based on occurring events. So there's condition = user register, action - create content.